# How to change the product list page to drop down refresh?

Tags: magento2.4, category-products, page, category-listing

I have two themes, one for PC and one for mobile. I want to change the product list page of mobile to the dropdown refresh mode.(Slide up to the bottom automatically loads the next page) What should I do?  If you have a good plan, thank you very much

Comment: do you mean you want to reload the page on the change of dropdown?

Comment: I want to change the page to a slide page (Slide up to the bottom automatically loads the next page)